# Searching for a paper on "$e$ is not expressible as a simple integral"

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, constants

I have seen a paper whose main aim was to explain a conjecture that $e$ is not expressible as the integral of a "simple function" over a "simple" region.  In contrast to $\pi$ which is easily expressible.  The paper was most likely in arXiv.org. I am  looking for the link. The exact terminology was likely different from "simple".

Edit :

[Periods](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/kontzagi.pdf), Kontsevich, Zagier

Comment: Do you mean "not a period"?

Comment: @Trebor  that could have been the terminology. Yes that is it, The paper by Kontsevich. thanks. If you wish to list it as the answer.

Comment: Kontsevich, Zagier "Periods"

Comment: Did this paper precise "simple function" and "simple region" ?

Comment: @Peter  They consider algebraic functions with rational coefficients and regions defined via such.